# Change color of the UIButton title navigation bar

Tags: swift, ios8, uibutton, navigationbar

When I create my navigation bar, I can place in left item, right item and in the title view, three buttons but only the left and right item have an animation and I can't change the color of the title button.

The creation of the buttons in the navigation bar :

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "VOYAGE", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goToPage1:")

    var buttonCenter = UIButton()
    buttonCenter.setTitle("PHOTOS", forState: .Normal)
    buttonCenter.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    buttonCenter.addTarget(self, action: "goToPage2:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonCenter

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "SIGHTINGS", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goToPage3:")
```

The changement of the color when in touche on button:

Function goToPage1 :

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor(red: 174/255, green: 211/255, blue: 43/255, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationItem.titleView!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Function goToPage2 :

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.titleView!.tintColor = UIColor(red: 174/255, green: 211/255, blue: 43/255, alpha: 1)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Function goToPage3 :

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.titleView!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor(red: 174/255, green: 211/255, blue: 43/255, alpha: 1)
```

Have you an idea for the selection animation of the button?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think you need to change the color of the button center not the titleView anymore

Comment: I have try it but it didn't work

Comment: did you use buttonCenter.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Comment: I have create "var buttonCenter: UIButton?" and I booted the button in the viewDidLoad as above but the color don't change.

Comment: Maybe you can try to set the button color and reassign it to the navigationItem.titleView everytime you want the color to be changed. e.g: buttonCenter.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal) self.navigationItem.titleView = buttonCenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this steps :

- in the main.storyboard, for each view, you can change in the simulated metrics section the value of top bar to translucent navigation bar
- add in the navigation item created your buttons
- link the buttons from main.storyboard to your file and change the color with `self.yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)`